# Rounding or decimals in binomial distribution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-distribution

if in a problem you are to find the probability of passing a course of more than x-percent people and the number is decimal, do you round to the nearest one or for every new natural number started you pick the upcoming natural number?

Eg. 3/4 of 47 people is 35.25 will you work with 35 or 36?

Answer (score 0):

The decision may depend on details of the problem formulation. Here, "more than $3/4$" can only mean "$36$ or more".